# I want to control the digital output port of Arduino with a web browser. What should I do?

Tags: web, arduino, port, out, digital

I controlled the equipment using the output port of aduino. But I want to control it through the Internet.How can I use Ethernet Shield to create and control webpages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a webserver with Arduino Ethernet or Wifi shield.

I found a shield which has a built-in web application, named 'PHPoC Shield for Arduino'. It lets you control the output port of Arduino on a webpage, like an embedded web application.

There's an [example project I can share on the forum using the PHPoC shield](http://www.phpoc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=253), and a [manual of PHPoC Arduino shield](http://phpoc.com/support/manual/p4s-348_user_manual).